# Should My string class supply implicit conversion to std::string

Tags: c++, c++11

I defined a string class and one of its constructors accepts std::string, that is to say std::string can be directly converted to my string.
And for some reason, I want to provide an implicit conversion method for my string to std::string.
It looks like:

```
class MyString {
public:
  MyString(const std::string& str) : data(str) {}

  operator const std::string& () const {
    return data;
  }

private:
  std::string data;
};
```

After I provided a method for implicit conversion to std::string, I only found a compilation error: the type selection error of the c++ ternary expression. Something like: b ? std::string("") : MyString("").

But I worry that there may be some unknown hazards in being able to convert from std::string to MyString, and directly from MyString to std::string. Is it OK? Why?
Thanks All.

Comment: Both parts of the ternary should return the same type. If you're creating and then instantly converting back that does seem really pointless.

Comment: Implicit conversion are usually dangerous or smell. There is very few situation where implicit conversion is recommended. If possible, just use `explicit` on both the constructor and the conversion operator

Comment: @tadman you are right, we'd modified the code of ternary

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot Because we have a lot of code that relies on the implicit conversion feature, we have to provide this method unless there are some very convincing cases that force us to abandon this method. Thanks

Comment: That's a very odd-looking conversion operator, BTW. Why return a `const` reference to a data member?

Comment: @sanerersan - Experience says that when you have conversions both ways, you will very soon find these "very convincing cases" where the compiler cannot decide if it should convert a to b, or b to a. The ternary problem is just the tip of the iceberg.

Comment: @AdrianMole We need to confirm the outer std::string won't change the value of mystring, that is the std::string caller get is like a new copy

Comment: @BoP I'm concerned about compiling fine but bugs due to incorrectly implemented implicit conversions. So I send this question to ask experienced c++ programmers if they have encountered such problems before. ^_^

Comment: Just returning a `std:string` *by value* will return a copy of the data member. That is also an *actual* conversion.

Comment: `std::string_view` is a more generic class to convert between string types.